# Authentication combination OpenID & Facebook

Tags: authentication, openid, facebook, web-applications

Is it possible to use a combination of authentication systems in a web app?

I want to use OpenId, however I think my potential customers are actually more likely to have a Facebook ID.

Therefore I wonder if it is possible to offer both types of authentication?

Comment: Of course it is possible if you build it from scratch - are you asking if it is possible within a particular framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For nearly every language there should be a Framework! You can chain/wrap the functionality of that frameworks to statisfy your needs!

In pseudocode:

```
if(IsUserValidViaOpenId() || IsUserValidByOwnAuthDB()) ...  user auth successful
```

If you use java, Acegi/Spring Security might be the best way (Security which isn't inversive - via AOP). There you can use openID and define an own second validator for yor own userdb!

Answer (score 3):

[Facebook has joined the OpenID foundation](http://openid.net/2009/02/05/facebook-joins-openid-foundation-board/), so perhaps they'll be implementing OpenID soon (in which case it may be better to just use OpenID).

Answer (score 2):

You want [RPX](http://www.rpxnow.com). It abstracts the whole mess of OpenID away from both you and your visitors. It also lets them authenticate with Facebook or MySpace in addition to the OpenID providers.

It provides a login interface very similar to what you see right here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: That's pretty cool - I might try it out in my next project. Thanks!

Comment: And it also makes you completely depending on a single external source for all your user authentication. Please read the arguments at http://blog.nerdbank.net/2009/01/why-using-rpxnow-is-bad-idea.html before deciding whether to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this in your form processing logic:

```
def authenticate(form_info):
    url = form_info['url']
    if (is_facebook_url(url)):
        return perform_facebook_authentication(form_info)
    else:
        return perform_open_id_authentication(form_info)
```